# From when it is possible to answer to a closed question?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions

As far as I know if a question will be closed and in the same time someone write an answer, then a message will appear to that person telling him that he can't answer anymore and everything what he wrote was in vain.

But (now I see first time) it seems that things are not really so:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things going on here:

- The server will allow submissions up to 4 hours after closure.
- The client-side javascript polls the server for question status roughly once every 45 seconds. If it sees the closure, it disables the form.
- Unless, that is, you've been writing long enough to have saved a draft. You might get a notice saying that the question is closed but your form will still work.

The draft system is what's responsible for the weirder outliers (I've seen hours-long delays before) and is [much newer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160753/post-answer-after-question-closed-and-banner-shows?lq=1) than the up-to-45-second window but this one could simply be a client-side delay issue.

You could probably force an answer through up to 4 hours later by just tinkering with the javascript to re-enable the form if you *really* wanted to. [Video showing you *can*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_n5ZQd7Xbw).

Answer (score 3):

People that started to write answers before the questions are closed have a leeway of 4 hours so they can submit their answers. [This is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79457/213575).

Comment: I'm sure that I saw many times that freaking message (*This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted*) before passing 4 hours.

Comment: That's not *exactly* what Jeff's answer says. As of that post, the backend allows a 4hour delay it but the frontend should be shutting down well before then. Jeff's post explains *up to* 45 seconds (which would cover this question). Though (and this should be stressed) that post is over three years old. Things do change.

Comment: @Oli what exactly Jeff says that differs from my answer?

Comment: Not all users who start writing are allowed to finish. If you haven't written enough, it'll shut you out.

Comment: @Oli right, I still don't see where I got it wrong "People that started to write *answers before the questions are closed*"

Comment: Because you can still be cut off if you haven't been writing long enough. If you don't make it to a draft savepoint, your form is locked down.